# Ignore 'long' specifier for custom type in c++

Tags: c++, templates, alias, quadruple-precision

I have a type and a template class

```
#ifdef USE_QUAD
using hybrid = __float128;
#else
using hybrid = double;
#endif

template<typename T>
struct Time {
    int day;
    long T dayFraction; // This is an example, I need both in here, T and long T;
};
```

And to make things complicated: A nesting class

```
template<typename T>
struct State {
    Time<T> time;
    std::vector<T> position;
}
```

Now I want to use the class in my code as `hybrid` and `double` simultaneously, like

```
State<hybrid> stateH; // sometimes precision needed
State<double> stateD; // precision never needed
```

and let the preprocessor take care of what hybrid is supposed to be.

The code, however, perfectly compiles if `hybrid = double`, but not so much, if `hybrid = __float128`, because of the `long T dayFraction;` in the Time class.

Is there a workaround to define an alias like

```
using long __float128 = float128;
```

?

I had a workaround with defining a `longHybrid` like:

```
#ifdef USE_QUAD
using hybrid     = __float128;
using longHybrid = __float128;
#else
using hybrid     = double;
using longHybrid = long double;
#endif
```

But forwarding two template parameters would affect a bit of code and feels kind of redundant.
I would love to hear any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually write `long T` and expect that to be interpreted as `long double` when `T` is `double`. If it works for you, that's a non-portable quirk of your compiler.

If you want "regular" and "long" versions of a type, different for `double` but the same for `float128`, one way to do it would be to define a template like this:

```
template <typename T> struct Longer {
    using type = T;
};
template <> struct Longer<double> {
    using type = long double;
};
```

Instead of `long T` in `struct Time`, use `typename Longer<T>::type`.

Comment: I just implemented this and it works fine. Thanks a lot!